# How to prevent same site cookies being sent on a cross origin request?

Tags: http, security, cookies, content-security-policy

I have two websites a.example.com (A) and b.example.com (B)

A embeds an iframe to B. B uses authentication cookie with full domain set, SameSite=Strict, Secure, HttpOnly and has CSP with frame-ancestors https://a.example.com. Because A and B are same site (eTLD+1 is the same) this cookie gets sent. It gets sent for initial GET of the iframe and also for follow up POSTs.

Is there a way to prevent this?

It seems that if an attacker compromises any website on example's intranet they will be able to clickjack any other website (unless it uses CSP and doesn't allow the compromised website).

Comment: _"and also for follow up POSTs"_ - made _from_ where? If these happen _inside_ the iframe, then that is not a cross-origin context any more.

Comment: Not sure why Strict would not work for the initial GET request for the iframe content though. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie "defines" a cross-site request as "such as on requests to load images or frames", which should match the scenario here.

Comment: Can you restrict by path in the cookie?

Comment: @HalvorSakshaug yes, but I would like to do it kind of the other way around. Allow auth cookie everywhere except on the iframed url. And then if there is compromised website it could still iframe other URLs

Comment: Same-Site cookies by definition are shared between subdomains. You need proper CSRF protection such as csrf tokens.

Comment: csrf tokens don't help against clickjacking, I need to do X-Frame-Options: DENY and break my iframe